# i tried every function but none of them work,i want the recognized speech to appear in Entrybox

Tags: python, tkinter

how do i solve this i want the speechrecognition to input the text into Entrybox which i named as entry_1,the code works properly when i dont use gui but doesnt display anything after i added tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
import wikipedia
import wolframalpha
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
import pyspeech

class gui:
#gui
 def __init__(self):
        frame=Frame(root,width=600,height=0)
        frame.pack()
        self.label_1 = Label(root, text="Ask your Question:")
        self.entry_1 = Entry(root)
        self.entry_1.bind("<Return>",self.virtual)
        self.label_1.pack(side=LEFT,pady=20)
        self.entry_1.pack(side=LEFT,fill=X,pady=20,padx=10,expand=TRUE)
        self.entry_1.focus_set()

 def virtual(self,event):

  value = self.entry_1.get()
  value=value.lower()
  if value=='': #checking if input is null

   r = sr.Recognizer()
   with sr.Microphone() as source:
                  audio = r.listen(source)
   try:

        self.entry_1.insert(r.recognize_google(audio)) 
   except sr.UnknownValueError:
                   print("google speech could not understand audio")
   except sr.RequestError as e:
                   print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
   else:
    try:
                   app_id = "some api" #enter you api
                   client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)
                   res = client.query(value)
                   answers = next(res.results).text
                   print(answers)

    except:
                  print(wikipedia.summary(value,sentences=2))

root=Tk()
root.wm_title("Hi,i am Karen your personal assistant") #title for gui
b=gui()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "can't take the words spoken" mean? Why can't it? Do you get an error? Does it put the wrong thing in the entry? Does the program crash? Have you verified that `r.recognize_google(audio)` returns what you think it should return?

Comment: nothing happens it doesn't display anything in the entrybox,it works fine when i dont use the gui.

Comment: @saivineeth: Should look like this: `.insert(0, r.recognize_google(audio))`